# SQL query if data match in string from column 2 alter column 22

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 22 columns.
The particular columns interesting are 2 and 22.

Column 2 has text URLs in each row. I want to to match if URL string contains "this text" then I want to alter column 22 to set number "1" instead of the deafult 0.

I want to do this check for all 600 000 rows in this table. Any idea how to form the query?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you'd show us the table structure, some data and a possible query - before asking future questions please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `Update` with `like` should do:

```
update your_table
set col_22 = 1
where col_2 like '%this text%';
```

If you want to make this update only on the rows where column 22 is set to 0 and column 2 contains the text you're looking for, then add another filter:

```
update your_table
set col_22 = 1
where col_2 like '%this text%'
and col_22 = 0;
```

Comment: i can't get it to work, it tells me unknown column 'col_2' where clause hmm

Comment: nevermind, new to sql, didnt relaize col_number wasn't a thing, had to use actual names of the columns.